# VS 2015 cordova android network simulation

Tags: android, visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to debug my Cordova App with VS2015 on the VS Android simulator.

My problem is that the simulator is not aware that he is connected to the internet. Even if I can access to the internet using the web browser, the system is still offline mode.

I tried to simulate the network with 4G connection or other but the system doesn't change it's connexion status.

When using WP simulator, my WP works very well and the connection works perfectly.

Is there someone that can help me with it ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Network Simulation and WiFi Simulation capabilities aren't wired up yet. Apologies for the confusion of having controls for Network Simulation that don't work--we share a lot of code with the Windows Phone Emulator, where this is a supported feature. The Android Emulator acts as if it is connected via Ethernet today (and this is not configurable), but look for Wifi and other network simulations in a future release!

Comment: Hey Pawel--it's working now! Check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/04/29/visual-studio-emulator-for-android-in-vs2015-rc.aspx

Comment: Hey John, it looks like it should but I'm having trouble. Can you have a look ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021277/how-to-connect-visual-studio-2015-android-emulator-to-network