# How to connect Visual Studio 2015 Android Emulator to network?

Tags: android-emulator, visual-studio-2015

I've recently installed  VS 2015 RC and the Android Emulator seems to work great(it is very fast :)) except it can not connect to network. According to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/04/29/visual-studio-emulator-for-android-in-vs2015-rc.aspx the emulator should be able to connect to my WiFi card. I had a look at the emulator in Hyper-V Admin UI and it is configured in the same way as Windows Phone Emulator which works just fine. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks guys for ideas. I uninstalled both Xamarin Android Player and Genymotion and now the VS Emulator works!

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem, when installed RC tools to a PC that had Genymotion previously installed, so what I did was disable the VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapters (that Genymotion used), and restarted the emulator, then the network on emulator was working

[image: Device Manager disabled network adapters]

Comment: As counter-intuitive as it may seem, I also had to choose "No" when the VS Emulator for Android asked me if I wanted to make changes to enable internet connectivity.  
  
----- Each time, I would go through and disable all of the VirtualBox adapters and delete the associated vEthernet adapters, only to have VS Emulator for Android re-enable the VirtualBox adapters and recreate the vEthernet adapters when I would choose "Yes" when prompted if I wanted the system to setup internet connectivity.

Comment: This answer saves me a lot of time. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

First, try disabling any virtual Ethernet adapters that aren't being used (eg. those used by Virtual Box). Next, go to Hyper-V Manager and delete any virtual switches then restart the emulator.

Comment: I might give it a try before next time I repave my machine. At the moment I need it to be in a working state and those changes are rather significant.

Answer (score 0):

My environment is a nested virtualization as follows:

**Physical machine (WinServer2016)** -> **VM (WinServer2016)** -> **VS Emulator for Android**

The only thing that worked for me was running the following command in the physical machine:

```
Set-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName $vmName -MacAddressSpoofing on
```

Where `$vmName` is the name of the WinServer2016 VM.

Answer (score 0):

for my 5.2" Marshmallow (6.0.0) (android 6.0 - API 23) in VS 2017 after connecting Wifi  and answering the question for Connecting the Emulator to network I got my virtual eth2 wifi which is visible as a wifi when you slide down the upper toolbar which you usually see if your networks are connected or not.

but in my previous tries this icon shows an exclamation mark and **no internet**  is shown beside it , after restarting and rerunning the emulator it works

[image: Visual Studio android emulator WiFi Icon]

Another useful points is in the network settings which my Hyper-V vEthernet with following name and note that under connectivity it shows **internet access** with Status of AndroidAPs7 which is name of WiFi connection and my Main Wi-Fi only shows **bridged** .

- vEthernet (1x1 11b g n Wireless LAN PCI Express Half Mini Card
  Adapter Virtual Switch)

[image]