# No internet connection for Visual Studio Android Emulator

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-emulator, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Android Emulator that comes with Visual Studio 2015. When I run it, in Wi-Fi settings of Android this status appears `Obtaining IP Address..` for `Wired eth1` network. But it fails after a long time.

---

## **What I've tried:**

- Removed all the `virtual switches` in `Virtual Switch Manager` of `Hyper-V` before running the emulator.
- Unchecked `automatic detect settings` in proxy settings
- Tried different API levels (19,22,..)
- Windows Phone Emulator doesn't have this problem and has internet connection.
- Restarted my PC!

---

## **What I guess:**

When I diagnose `vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch)` it says it has an invalid IP address. Also inside android emulator it tries to obtain an IP. Obviously I need to give the emulator a valid IP, but I don't know how or where or what value.

How to give the Android emulator internet access?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It looks like Android is unable to acquire an IP address from DHCP.

In `Hyper-V Manager` (`virtmgmt.msc`), select the VM for the emulator profile you are trying to start and go to its `Settings...` (right click for context menu or see action pane on right side).

Under `Hardware`, make sure there are two virtual switches:

1. `Emulator Internal Network Adapter`
2. `Emulator External Network Adapter`

`Emulator External Network Adapter` must be listed as the second adapter -- the order matters. If they are ordered incorrectly, delete the External adapter and recreate it, giving it the same settings it had before. You can create it by clicking `Add Hardware` in the VM's hardware list.

[image: Hyper-V Manager - VM Settings]

Comment: Indeed with second adapter as external one it works!
Very strange that it requires the second adapter...

Comment: I could put a static IP and it worked for me. See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021277/how-to-connect-visual-studio-2015-android-emulator-to-network/43615819#43615819).

Comment: This worked! Thank you so very much. I ran into a hiccup adding the external switch, if anyone else does as well, read this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2486812/creating-v-switches-within-the-hyper-v-environment-fails

Comment: New machine, fresh install of VS 2017 and Xamarin on a new machine. I didn't have internet access when I launched the VS Emulator. This answer helped me look into the Hyper-V settings and see that there was only an internal adapter, no external. Once I added an external adapter (for my internet connection) I had to close Hyper-V and boot up the emulator, then close it again. Then I opened Hyper-V again and the adapter showed in the Emulator settings. I switched the order you mentioned here, then the emulator booted up with internet access.

Comment: I don't see the Emulator External Network Adapter on the Add Hardware list

Comment: What is missing from this answer is that you have to add a new virtual switch to be the external network adaptor in Hyper-V Manager.  So this... http://blog.tpcware.com/2017/03/visual-studio-2017-android-emulation/

Answer (score 6):

I fixed it by setting the second network adapter to Default switch and not the physical network adapter[Screen Grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYIHP.png).

Answer (score 5):

Thought this might help someone out there. Mine had an internet connection, but suddenly it stopped connecting. I resolved it by restarting my emulator with factory settings.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me adding an external adapter for each physical one (lan/wifi) worked but only when the virtual LAN identification was unchecked on each of them.

Answer (score 0):

For unknown reasons by default my second adapter was set to `VirtualBox Host Ethernet`
I've changed it to `Intel Dual Band` and now all works even without emulator restart!

[image]