# Visual Studio Android Emulator Internet Connection on Azure

Tags: visual-studio, azure, android-emulator, azure-virtual-machine, visual-studio-emulator

I currently have a VM hosted on azure and I am trying to run visual studio android emulator on it. The installation worked perfectly and I am able to connect to the emulator. However, once connected, there is no internet connection for some reason.

I have tried modifying hyper-v's virtual switches, re-install, etc but the internet connection seems to remain inactive.

I am just wondering whether I would need to do any setup on azure portal in order to enable the emulator to access internet?

I really appreciate any support.

Regards,

Demerson

Comment: What do you mean "there is no internet connection "? Could you access google website? Could you show any screenshots?

Comment: I mean that I am not able to use anything that uses internet. For example, when I open the browser, or search or do anything that involves internet, I can't get results since it appears to not be connected.

When I open the browser, I get "Error_Name_Not_resolved".

Please see images below:
http://tinypic.com/r/15ausg/9

http://tinypic.com/r/zsr0g2/9

Comment: It seems that you could try this method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797558/no-internet-connection-for-visual-studio-android-emulator

Comment: Hey Nancy,

I have tried all of those, unfortunately it does not work :(

My last trial was to change the DNS info for the external virtual switch to 8.8.8.8 and the alternate DNS to 8.8.4.4 but it did not work either. 

I wonder whether it has anything to do with the fact that I am running it on an azure VM. I think I may have be forgetting to set up something on the VM? Perhaps it is a combination of DNS + Azure setup.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have added an external adapter for the second adaptor? More details about enabling internet connection from this [blog](http://blog.tpcware.com/2017/03/visual-studio-2017-android-emulation/), also check if [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/05/08/hyper-v-android-emulator-support/) can help.