# VS 2017 RC - No Internet in Hyper-V Android Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, visual-studio-2017

I am having a strange problem in VS 2017 RC, I know it's still quite buggy but maybe someone here can shed some light on my problem.

I have configured 2 devices in VS Emulators, one is for "Windows 10 Phone 14393.0" which runs fine and I have internet access but the other one for Android doesn't have internet access. The only settings I found different (apart from processor and RAM and such) were the network adapters.

Windows Phone emulator uses two network adapters, one is for data transfer which is used internally in both of the emulators and is common for them but the other one is a NAT switch which I believe is used for internet access.

The problem is Android emulator only creates the first adapter for data pass-through and doesn't create the 2nd one for internet. Now I am able to create 2nd adapter and save the settings but as soon as I try to deploy any app it asks me to configure the network settings on emulator and I have to choose yes or it doesn't start the emulator. Now if I choose yes it replaces the configuration and removes the 2nd adapter and I guess that is why I am not able to access internet.

So can someone help me on this so it doesn't replace settings and let me use the emulator with modified settings?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/a/39443659/736079

Comment: I explained the problem it changes the network configuration every time so even if I change the configuration myself it replaces it and yes I have changed the configuration so many times.

Comment: It mentions the deletion of the network bridge and selecting your Internet adapter instead if an internal adapter. None of the setups for Android I have require two adapters. Just hook it up to the Internet on a shared adapter directly.

Comment: I have tried everything but if I try to make it external as you said, it gives an error and doesn't let me change that although the windows creates a Network Bridge but still it doesn't work. So is there a way to open the Android Emulator through CMD as it can be done for Windows Emulator?

Comment: I am finally able to access internet after reinstalling windows, I guess there was a problem in windows which wasn't letting me use it for some reason.