# Upload File Using RestSharp and Xamarin

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin.android, restsharp, nancy

I already tried all threads I found here and none of them helped me. 
My Problem is, that I try to upload a file to a REST server. This Server is built with NancyFX. The route to upload a file looks like this

```
Put["/upload_prj"] = _ =>
        {
            if(!Directory.Exists(pfad))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(pfad);
            }
            var file = Request.Files.Single();
            var fullName = Path.Combine(pfad, file.Name);

            using (var fileStream = File.Create(fullName))
            {

                file.Value.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }

            return HttpStatusCode.OK;
        };
```

When using curl the file upload works fine. when I'm using a Windows Console App written in C# and using RestSharp everything works fine.
This is the code I use in the Console App:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("http://192.168.32.90:1234");
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("/upload_prj");
request.Method = Method.PUT;
request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;;
byte[] dataToUpload = File.ReadAllBytes("test.txt");
request.AddFileBytes("test.txt", dataToUpload, "test.txt");
var response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode.ToString());
```

When I'm using the exat same code in an Android app written in C# using Xamarin, I get as status code a 0 and nothing is uploaded.

Already deactivated the windows Firewall, tried to use POST instead of PUT and read almost every thread I found here.

Anyone here who can help me?

Comment: When you say you deactivated windows Firewall, that sounds like you're testing this on an Android emulator on your desktop.  Have you confirmed that the emulator can access the internet and that IP before attempting the upload?  Maybe the virtual network adapter for the emulator is set to host only, which seems to be default. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32913005/1549649

Comment: Yes, I'm using Android emulator. I deactivated the firewal because I thougth that that could be the problem. Every other request to the REST server works fine, so the emulator has access to the IP (and to the Internet). Also tested it on a S9 with the same result.