# Unable To Connect Visual Studio Android Emulator to Fiddler Proxy

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-emulator, visual-studio-2015, fiddler

I'm attempting to connect the Visual Studio Android Emulator v. 1.0.50813.2 through Fiddler as a proxy so I can monitor some network traffic for an application I'm writing.

I've followed the MS provided instructions to a T. (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/05/06/using-fiddler-to-monitor-network-traffic-from-the-vs-emulator-for-android.aspx) still I get a "net:ERR_TIMED_OUT" message when attempting to hit the Fiddler echo endpoint.

I've also tried following the instructions in [How to connect Visual Studio 2015 Android Emulator to network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021277/how-to-connect-visual-studio-2015-android-emulator-to-network) as I had the Xamarin Android Player installed at one point.

I'm trying to use the current VS Emulator 5.1-inch Lollipop (5.1.1) XXHDPI phone emulator environment, but I've also tried the VS Emulator 5-inch KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI phone environment as well. Both produce the same results.

The emulator will connect to the network just fine without the proxy being set up. I've completely disabled the Windows firewall so that shouldn't be an issue.

The Fiddler proxy echo service works just fine on the host operating system (Windows 8.1) and the Loopback extensions have been added to ensure that it isn't a problem with app container isolation.

Does anyone know how I can correct this and get the VS emulator to correctly interface with Fiddler? I'm OK switching to anything more recent than Android API Level 15.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with Fiddler

its odd but I read some where to uninstall Fiddler and then reinstall it worked for me

give it a go and let me see how you go

just got mine working now