# Visual Studio Android Emulator network not working

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator

I started using xamarin in visual studio, and I installed visual studio android emulator. Emulator works flawlessly, but network on it doesn't. In settings it says it's connected, but browser can't open websites. I started windows phone emulator, and there network works without problem. When I started android emulator, it added two network adapters (see picture). In hyper-v virtual device settings for Android emulator, internal network adapter is set to windows phone adapter (see on picture), and external is set to Realtek bla bla bla. I tried deleting all virtual switches, deleting emulator and going all over again, and nothing helps. I assume  the problem is in android emulator or hyper-v settings, because windows phone emulator works all right (it uses same internal adapter, but has no external in hyper-v settings). Does anyone have idea how to solve this? Thanks in advance! 
[image]

Comment: If you are using the emulator that comes from Google as part of the Android SDK, don't. Download either Genymotion or use Xamarin Android Player.

Comment: @Eclipsed4utoo I downloaded "Visual studio emulator for Android". I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect Visual Studio 2015 Android Emulator to network?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021277/how-to-connect-visual-studio-2015-android-emulator-to-network)

Answer (score 6):

Seems like the installation of the Visual Studio Emulator for Android might have gone wrong. You can check the Network settings in the Hyper-V manager.

For the two images I use it looks like this

**Internal Network Adapter**
[image: Hyper-V internal network screenshot]

**External Network Adapter**
[image: Hyper-V external network screenshot]

So the problem might be something with the External setting as it can't connect to the Internet.

I see you have a virtual switch which is similar to the one I have for my Intel NIC. If you go to Virtual Switch Manager in the options menu on the right, the Virtual Switch Properties for your virtual switch should look like this:

[image: Virtual Switch Settings]

Comment: Maybe try make a new virtual switch?

Comment: Tried that too, still same. I will find another emulator, and see what happens.

Comment: If you are going to use VirtualBox or Intel HAXM, make sure you disable Hyper-V or you won't get hardware acceleration working.

Comment: I have amd processor, and i had vmware until couple of days ago (i uninstalled it). Does that make any difference?

Comment: Dunno, it might have upset Hyper-V having two hypervisors installed, or something has messed up the Hyper-V network stuff. There are some other answers here: http://superuser.com/questions/469806/windows-8-hyper-v-how-to-give-vm-internet-access

Comment: I know we're not supposed to comment but THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the same problem. First, do you have LAN and WiFi on your computer/laptop. If you do test it out by disabling the LAN in your Network settings or Computer hardware manager and connecting through WiFi. If that works then you have the same problem I had. This is caused because the Hyper-V Network Switch setup for the Android Emulator prefers to use the WiFi Connection of your computer when it sets up the Network Switch.

Solve this by:

1. Uninstalling the Android Emulator from Visual Studio.
2. Go into Hyper-V and delete the "VS Emulator..." VMs and the extra Virtual Network Switches created by the Android Emulator
3. Disable your WiFi so you are ONLY connected by LAN
4. Reinstall the Visual Studio Android Emulator
5. Run Emulator and agree to let it setup the internet for you.
6. Test the Emulator is connected to the internet by LAN.
7. Shutdown the Emulator and re-enable your WiFi.
8. Run the Emulator again and let it setup the internet for you again.

You can now re-enable your LAN or use your WiFi.

Comment: Hey, how can i uninstall the Android Emulator form Visual Studio and install it again? :) Thanks in advance!