# Xamarin Forms Image Loading Error

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to display an image in the "Xamarin forms" but I got below error:

```
Image Loading: Error getting stream for http://www.example.com/example.jpg *(example only)*: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure
```

I had tested that the URL of the image,and it was able to display on the browser.

Below is My code in code-behind:

```
var imageSource = new UriImageSource { Uri = new Uri("http://www.Example.com/example.jpg") } ;
            image.Source = imageSource;
```

And below is the code that I use in Xaml:

```
<Image x:Name="image" />
```

After I google for the solution,I found that **ModernHttpClient** might be a solution but I have no idea how to implement it.

Or isn't possible I could solve the error without using **ModernHttpClient**?

Please advice!

Comment: `Error: NameResolutionFailure` Whatever url you are actually using, the domain name was not resolved....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

It was because by default,the emulator was not configured to connect to internet,hence the image couldn't load from internet.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622890/visual-studio-android-emulator-network-not-working) is the solution to configure the emulator network card.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string imageURI = "https://s9.postimg.org/aq1jt3fu7/handshake.87122244_std.jpg";
System.Uri uri;

async void LoadImage()
{
    System.Uri.TryCreate(imageURI, UriKind.Absolute, out uri);
    Task<ImageSource> result = Task<ImageSource>.Factory.StartNew(() => ImageSource.FromUri(uri));
    img.Source = await result;
}
```