# Visual Studio Android emulator is connected to network but no internet access

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator, xamarin.android, emulation

I am running visual studio on a machine in a network. Visual Studio Android emulator is connected to network, but no internet access!!!
I have been struggling about one month to connect Visual Studio Android emulator to internet, but I can't. I know something is wrong with my network setting, but I do not know what it is, because when I take my machine out of Lan network, and use wifi adapter to connect to internet, Visual Studio Android emulator can connect to internet fine.

What I've tried thus far:

- Removed all the virtual switches in Virtual Switch Manager of Hyper-V before running the emulator.
- create virtual switches manually
- Uncheck automatic detect settings in proxy settings
- Try different API levels (19,22,..)
- Reinstall visual studio
- Even clean reinstall Widows 10 !!!

[image]

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx#Anchor_2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect Visual Studio 2015 Android Emulator to network?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021277/how-to-connect-visual-studio-2015-android-emulator-to-network)