# Visual Studio 2015 Android Emulator internet connection problems

Tags: visual-studio-2015, android-emulator, hyper-v, internet-connection

I've gone through dozens of different solutions to this problem already, yet I am still unable to solve it.

I just recently installed the Visual Studio Android Emulator. It runs fine and applications get deployed successfully and everything is as fast as it should be, but there is *no internet connection*.

At first it was stuck at "`Obtaining IP address...`" - I later fixed this by going into advanced options in the WiFi window and setting the IP setting from DHCP to Static and filled in all the necessary fields. It then successfully connected to the WiFi - but now it has no internet connection and I can't seem to get it to work.

[image]

## My IP configuration:

[image: CMD IP configuration]

## WiFi settings on the device:

[image: WiFi settings on the device]

## Hyper-V device settings:

[image: Hyper-V device settings - internal adapter]
[image: Hyper-V device settings - external adapter]

## Hyper-V Virtual-Switch manager:

[image: Virtual-Switch manager settings]

And this is how my connections look like in Control panel:
[image: Control Panel - network settings]
I have no other Virtual network adapters installed apart from Hyper-V.

## Already tried:

- XDECleanup
- VS Emulator installation repair
- Hyper-V & VS Emulator reinstall
- Multiple system reboots
- Removing all virtual switches and letting VS add them automatically

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect Visual Studio 2015 Android Emulator to network?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021277/how-to-connect-visual-studio-2015-android-emulator-to-network)